# Can't access KML features

Tags: openlayers-3

I am loading a KML file locally and I have been able to add it to the map successfully. However, I want to interate over the features and can't seem to get anything to work. My code currently:

```
var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: '/kml/sample.kml',
        format: new ol.format.KML()
    })
});

// Iterate over features *NOT WORKING*
myLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
})
```

Any pointers on how I can get the forEachFeature to function, or any alternative method, would be great.

Comment: What do "can't get anything to work" and "NOT WORKING" mean?

Comment: There aren't any features as far as I can tell since the forEachFeature loop doesn't execute. As well, when I do a myLayer.getSource().getFeatures() an empty array is returned. The features are displayed on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your question works fine, except that the features are loaded asynchronously. Most of the time it will first execute forEachFeature, which finds 0 features to loop through and afterwards the features are loaded.

You may find out that a single feature is loaded by listening for the addfeature event of the source and maybe you can make your desired changes there for each feature separately:

```
var id = 1;
myLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', function (ev_add) {
    console.log(ev_add.feature);
    ev_add.feature.once('change', function (ev_change) {
        console.log(ev_change.target.getId());
    });
    ev_add.feature.setId(x);
    x += 1;
});
```

If you must wait until all features are loaded, the change event of the layer can help:

```
myLayer.once('change', function () {
    myLayer.getSource().forEachFeature(function (feature) {
        console.log(feature);
    });
});
```

**Edit: You are right, the addfeature event handler has the event object as parameter. To your question about setting the ID while adding features, I think that this is again a problem of waiting until the changes are done. I made the amendments in the first snippet.**

Comment: Thanks E.Nerv, I had to make a small change since the 'addfeature' listener returns the event instead of the feature. Worked with myLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', function (event) {
    console.log(event.feature);
});

Comment: I noticed that I can't edit any feature using on 'addFeature' - the changes (e.g. setting the Id via setId()) don't get saved to the feature. If I wait until all features are added (e.g. via layer.once 'change') an iterate through them, the changes are saved. Is there a way to change features as they are added? This would be far more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get this to work. Not sure if it's the most efficient however:

```
var featProj = map.getView().getProjection();
var kmlFormat = new ol.format.KML();
var myLayer = new ol.layer.Vector();

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function() {
        $.ajax( {
            url: '/kml/my.kml',
            success: function( data ) {
                var features = kmlFormat.readFeatures( data, { featureProjection: featProj } ); 
                vectorSource.addFeatures( features );

                // iterate over features
                vectorSource.forEachFeature( function( feature ) {
                    //do something
                    console.log( feature );
                });
            }
        }); 
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
myLayer.setSource( vectorSource );
```